# Kusto query to get the file extension from the message log using regex

Tags: regex, kql

I am trying to get the file extension from the Kusto message log. Below is how my log looks:

```txt
"Symchk result for D:\pkgshadow\19H1\999907\files.csi\arm64\neutral\fre\Microsoft-OneCore-VirtualizationBasedSecurity-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.21380.1020.mum is NOTAPPLICABLE"
```

I wanted to get the extension "**mum**" from the above log.

Below is the query I have tried but it is not working.

```
| extend filepath = trim_start("Symchk result for ", trim_end(" is NOTAPPLICABLE", ParsedMsg))
| extend extension = extract(**@"([^\\]*\.\w+\s)"**, 1, filePath)
| project extension
```

I am getting the file (i.e. **Microsoft-OneCore-VirtualizationBasedSecurity-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.21380.1020.mum**) as an output using the above regex. I wanted to get the extension of file (i.e. **mum**).
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hi @Arvund. Two different people answered your question. Please check the answers, vote up the ones that help you, and accept the one that helped you the most (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why).

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
print @"Symchk result for D:\pkgshadow\19H1\999907\files.csi\arm64\neutral\fre\Microsoft-OneCore-VirtualizationBasedSecurity-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.21380.1020.mum is NOTAPPLICABLE"
| project extract("\\.([a-z]{3}) ", 1, print_0)
```

Output:

`mum`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group using [extract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractfunction).

```
[^\\]*\.(\w+)\s
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^\\]*` Optionally match any char except `\`
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in group 1
- `\s` Match a whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2qDPUI/1)